# Twitter Bootstrap - Two Column layout for <form>

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

In Bootstrap 2.3, is there a standardized way to have a two-column layout for an HTML `<form>` with labels/inputs/actions? I don't see any in the documentation.

An example image of what I want: https://i.stack.imgur.com/fOLom.png

As an aside, I need there to be a solid background color that spans the entire width of the `div.span12` or other enclosing container.  Having two `.span6` causes a break in the background color in the center (which I suppose can be fixed by wrapping the two `.span6` in a `div.clearfix` with the background class applied?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Easy stuff. Bring the bootstrap row within a parent div and set the background of that div to a color of your choosing.

The Markup:

```
<div id="background-color">
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action=""><!-- START THE FORM -->
<div class="row-fluid">

<div class="span6"> <!-- FIRST COLUMN -->
<label>First Name</label>
  <label for="textfield"></label>
  <input type="text" />
  <label>Last Name</label>
  <label for="textfield"></label>
  <input type="text"  />
</div>

<div class="span6"> <!-- SECOND COLUMN -->
<label>Other</label>
  <label for="textfield"></label>
  <input type="text" />
  <label>Fields</label>
  <label for="textfield"></label>
  <input type="text"  />

  <input type="submit" name="button" id="button" value="Submit" />
</form> <!-- END THE FORM -->
</div>
</form>

</div> <!-- End row -->

</div> <!-- END BACKGROUND -->
```

The CSS:

```
#background-color {background-color: #CCC;}
```

I hope this helps

Comment: How does this work in Bootstrap 3? Do I just use the col-xs-6?

Answer (score 2):

To my understanding for Bootstrap 3 these changes are required;

- all code sitting in container to access grid system [info here](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#overview-container)
- span to col for new version
- use device class as suits your requirements [info here](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-options)
- labels and controls wrapped in form-group for spacing [info here](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms)
- form class to form-horizontal removes the need for row divs *(i have used nested columns without rows, seems to display correctly with form-horizontals function)*
- panel used to frame the form as pictured

  ```
  <div class="container">
      <div class="panel panel-default" style="background-color: #CCC">
          <div class="panel-body">
              <form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="" class="form-horizontal"><!-- START THE FORM -->
                  <div class="col-sm-6"> <!-- FIRST COLUMN -->
                      <div class="form-group">
                          <label for="inputFirstname" class="col-sm-4 control-label">First Name</label>
                          <div class="col-sm-8">
                          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputFirstname" placeholder="First Name">
                          </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="form-group">
                          <label for="inputLastname" class="col-sm-4 control-label">Last Name</label>
                          <div class="col-sm-8">
                          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputLastname" placeholder="Last Name">
                          </div>
                      </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-sm-6"> <!-- SECOND COLUMN -->
                      <div class="form-group">
                          <label for="inputEmail" class="col-sm-4 control-label">Email</label>
                          <div class="col-sm-8">
                          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputEmail" placeholder="Email">
                          </div>
                      </div>

                      <div class="form-group">
                          <label for="inputUsername" class="col-sm-4 control-label">Username</label>
                          <div class="col-sm-8">
                          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputUsername" placeholder="Username">
                          </div>
                      </div>
                  </div>
          </form> <!-- END THE FORM -->
          </div>
      </div><!-- END PANEL -->
  </div>
  ```