# Twitter Bootrstrap -- Two column Layout for form not aligning properly

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I tried this [Twitter Bootstrap - Two Column layout for <form>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17158611/twitter-bootstrap-two-column-layout-for-form)

I have the following code:

```
I have the following code 

 <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-6">
            I’m on the left
                    <div>
                        fruits:
                    </div>
            <select class="form-control">
                <option value="1">Apple</option>
                <option value="2">orange</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6">
            I’m on the right
                 <div>
                     fruits:
                 </div>
            <select class="form-control">
                <option value="1">Apple</option>
                <option value="2">orange</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
```

and the output is like [image]

But I want the DropDown to be at the right of "fruits" and not below that. 
Am I missing something? I tried col-xs-6 and col-lg-6.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your label, "fruits" is inside a div which is a block element - meaning it will take up a whole width so you would expect the select to be below. What you'll want to do is look at the "form-horizontal" class in [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms).

Something like this:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form">

  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Fruits</label>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <select class="form-control">
        <option value="1">Apple</option>
        <option value="2">orange</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Fruits</label>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <select class="form-control">
        <option value="1">Apple</option>
        <option value="2">orange</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Note that there are a few approaches you can take with grid - this is just one.

Comment: I voted this as accepted because it does not use any extra css. If its going to be just label, I don't think we need to have the html helper <label for="inputemail3">.

Comment: True. leftover from my pasting :) But the for is nice for accessibility. Cleaning up....

Answer (score 2):

I have adjusted your HTML, Please have a look.

**[Working Demo](http://bootply.com/102986)**

HTML

```
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-6">
            <div class="form-group">
                <div>
                    I’m on the left
                </div>
                <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">fruits:</label>
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <select class="form-control">
                        <option value="1">Apple</option>
                        <option value="2">orange</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6">
            <div class="form-group">
                <div>
                    I’m on the left
                </div>
                <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">fruits:</label>
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <select class="form-control">
                        <option value="1">Apple</option>
                        <option value="2">orange</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

**Some Extra CSS**

```
.form-horizontal .control-label {
text-align: left;
  padding-left:0;
}

.form-horizontal .form-group {
margin: 0;
}
```